# Relacionamento Muitos pra Muitos Entity Framework Code First Chaves Primárias Compostas Coluna Repetida

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

na minha aplicação eu tenho duas entidades com um relacionamento de muitos pra muitos, a saber, **Atividade** e **Skill**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O EF (Code First) gera pra mim a tabela de junção, mas está dando conflito se eu crio o mapeamento na mão no **OnModelCreating** porque eu tenho a mesma coluna (ID_CLIENTE) nas duas tabelas (e não posso tirar ID_CLIENTE de nenhuma delas). Se eu deixo gerar sem mapear, cria a coluna ID_CLIENTE duas vezes (com nomes diferentes).

Existe alguma forma de configurar a criação da tabela **Skill_Atividade** sem que eu tenha que criar a entidade e os relacionamentos na mão?

**Models:**

```
public class Atividade
{
    public Atividade()
    {
        Skills = new List<Skill>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill
{
    public Skill()
    {
        Activities = new List<Atividade>();
    }

    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Atividade> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

**Código do fluent API**

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>()
            .HasMany(t => t.Activities)
            .WithMany(t => t.Skills)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("SKILL_ATIVIDADE");
                m.MapLeftKey("SkillId", "CustomerId");
                m.MapRightKey("Id", "CustomerId");
            });
```

Esse código não funciona porque eu repito a propriedade nas duas entidades, se eu mudar o nome da propriedade deve funcionar, mas ai eu vou ter a mesma coluna com nomes diferentes...

Comment: Você pode [edit] e adicionar na pergunta como estão os models?

Comment: Você configurou elas como foreign key?

Comment: @jbueno fiz a edição...

Comment: @FilipeAndradeLopes Você tá fazendo os mapeamentos com fluent ou tá automático?

Comment: @jbueno tentei das duas formas. Como meu banco usa um padrão diferente pros nomes de tabela não dá pra ser automático, mas o automático gera a coluna ID_CLIENTE duas vezes, uma pra cada entidade. Vou colocar o código do fluent API.

Comment: @denis então...o que eu fiz foi tentar mapear usando o fluent API, mas não fiz FKs explicitamente.

Comment: @FilipeAndradeLopes da uma olhada aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx